# Diophantine equations/Diophantine Geometry

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, diophantine-equations, diophantine-approximation

I am very knew to this site and I am eagerly waiting for solutions of:

> (1) Let $x$ be an algebraic number with degree $n > 1$. Then there
>   exists only finitely many rational numbers $p/q$ (in lowest terms)
>   such that $|x-(p/q)|  < 1/q^n$. Can you generalize the above cited
>   statement in more detailed manner?
>
> (2) Let $P$= $(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ be in $P^n (Q)$. Then the
>   logarithmic height of $P$ is defined by $H(P)$=
>   $\sum$(max{$|$$x_1$$|_p$,$|$$x_2$$|_p$,...,$|$$x_n$$|_p$}), where p is
>   in M. How this is defined?kindly explain with good example, if
>   necessary.
>
> (3) Let $S$ be a projective space over a number field and our function
>   @ to be a rational function, then through their substitution, how can
>   we investigate the iterates of @ using the ideas and tools from both
>   Diophantine geometry and Dynamical systems?

The all cited questions, I found in literature. Due to poor knowledge in Number Theory, especially Diophantine equations and Geometry, I could not get. Kindly explain.

Comment: I suggest starting a new thread for each question you have, as well as detailing any thoughts you have on each of the questions.

Comment: I guess that you are reading books by Silverman - you will get better answers if you say a bit about your background. Anyway, for (1), the keyword to search is Roth's theorem.

Comment: Maybe the thing to do is first better your knowledge of Number Theory, and come back to these questions when you are ready for them.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Siegel%E2%80%93Roth_theorem

Comment: @Thank you for your information.

Comment: I am doing something similar and I found Professor Silverman's [Arithmetic Dynamics notes](http://swc.math.arizona.edu/aws/2010/index.html) for Arizona winter school a good introduction. You might find it useful. Edit: I just realized this was almost one year ago... >_<